# Black screen after splash on iOS (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin

Note: I'm using an iPhone 5 and Xamarin. I have an Indie license.

When I try to run a debug build (connected to my machine) my app launches, the splash screen is fine, and then I get a black screen. The app hasn't crashed, and the debugger is stuck in a "Waiting for debugger to connect" mode.

I can run a release build no problem on my phone, and I can run debug builds in the simulator without a problem. But running a debug build on my phone, that results in a black screen and "waiting to debug"

Comment: Does it happen with any project, or just one in particular? Is anything written to the iOS Device Log when this happens?

Comment: There's nothing written in the log. I'll try with another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After catching all exceptions and logging them, and numerous other activities to try and determine what all apps, even new ones, caused the black screen I deleted all of the apps I had created off my phone, did a Clean of the build of my main app, and redeployed.

The application now loads in debug mode and runs as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue and couldn't find a fix.

There was a work-around that worked for me though: debugging over WiFi.